# Qt building nmake fatal error U1077: 'cd': return code '0×2'

Tags: qt

I am building qt5.7.0 from its source package with vs2015, following some instructions from the post [How to Build Qt 5.7 Statically Using MSVC14](http://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/09/22/how-to-build-qt-5-7-statically-using-msvc14-microsoft-visual-studio-2015/) .

Here is my configure commands:

```
configure -static -debug-and-release -prefix “C:\Qt\5.7.0” -platform win32-msvc2015
```

Then the building processing is initiated by type `nmake`, but after a while it is stopped due to the error, namke fatal error U1077, as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Add `-opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests` to configure and rerun nmake. What happens?

Comment: @sirop: I have solved issue by reconfiguring again with typing 'jom' instead of 'nmake'

Answer (score 0):

```
nmake clean
```

Download `jom` as a replacement of `nmake` for the building process (reconfigure and build)